# time bucketing with cumsum condition

Tags: kdb

Hello Fellow Kdb Mortals :D

Stuck on a pretty weird problem here. I have a table like

`time` col is xbar-ed to 5-mins

```
time    code     name    count
--------------------------------
00:00   SPY      S&P..   15
00:00   QQQ      ...     88
00:00   IWM      ...     100
00:00   XLE      ...     80
00:05   QQQ      ...     20
00:05   SPY      ...     75
00:10   QQQ      ...     22
00:10   XLE      ...     10
00:15   SPY      ...     23
.....   
.....
23:40   XLE      ...     11
23:50   SPY      ...     16
23:55   IWM      ...     100
23:55   QQQ      ...     10
```

What I want to be returned is a table like (from asc time)

```
code     name    stime     etime    cumcount
------------------------------------------------
SPY      S&P...  00:00     00:15    123                <-- 15+75+23 
QQQ      ...     00:00     00:05    108                <-- 88+20
IWM      ...     00:00     00:00    100                <-- 100     
XLE      ...     00:00     23:40    101                <-- 80+10+11
```

Notice there is a condition on this time bucket, where the first cumulative sum `by (code,name)` is greater than or equal to 100.

I can also generate another table from bottoms up (desc time)

```
code     name    stime     etime    cumcount
------------------------------------------------
SPY      ...     23:50     20:10    103                
QQQ      ...     23:55     21:45    118                
IWM      ...     23:55     23:55    100                
XLE      ...     23:40     00:00    101                <-- 11+10+80
```

I have been at this for a couple of hours, but can't get this working. Basic `select` and `sums` don't get me anywhere. I could use loops but thought I should check in here first before I go down that lane.

Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: Could you provide an example of the code you're using to generate these tables? It's not entirely obvious what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a table sorted ascending on time i.e.:

```
`time xasc `t
```

Something like this could work

```
q)t1:update cumcount:sums cnt,stime:first time by code,name from t
q)select code,name,stime,etime:time, cumcount from t1 where cumcount>=100,i=(first;i) fby ([]code;name)
```

Notice that I have relabelled `count` as `cnt` to prevent a clash with the `count` function that already exists in the `q` language.

So first you calculate your cumulative count in the update statement.
Then select from the resulting table in such a way that first you pull out only those records where the count is > 100, then you use fby to filter down on this again to pull out the first record for each distinct `(code;name)` pair.

In this example `stime` is the time of the first entry for each `(code;name)` pair and `etime` will be time when it first exceeds 100.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Seans solution, but for the sake of alternative:

```
q)t:update name:string lower code from([]time:"u"$0 0 0 0 5 5 10 10 15 1420 1430 1435 1435;code:`SPY`QQQ`IWM`XLE 0 1 2 3 1 0 1 3 0 3 0 2 1;cnt:15 88 100 80 20 75 22 10 23 11 16 100 10);

q)exec{x x[`cumcnt]binr 100}[([]stime:first time;etime:time;cumcnt:sums cnt)]by code,name from t
code name | stime etime cumcnt
----------| ------------------
IWM  "iwm"| 00:00 00:00 100
QQQ  "qqq"| 00:00 00:05 108
SPY  "spy"| 00:00 00:15 113
XLE  "xle"| 00:00 23:40 101
```

Summing from the bottom would be:

```
q)exec{x x[`cumcnt]binr 100}[([]stime:last time;etime:reverse time;cumcnt:sums reverse cnt)]by code,name from t
code name | stime etime cumcnt
----------| ------------------
IWM  "iwm"| 23:55 23:55 100
QQQ  "qqq"| 23:55 00:00 140
SPY  "spy"| 23:50 00:05 114
XLE  "xle"| 23:40 00:00 101
```